# Cross-lagged model with more than two variables (SEM)

Tags: structural-equation-modeling, autoregressive

I was wondering if anyone could point me to some literature discussing cross-lagged structural equation models with more than two variables: all the materials I found keep it very simple, and I unfortunately  cannot extrapolate that to more complicated models.

For instance, let's say there are two variables X1 and Z1 hypothesized to cause Y1, and for all of them we have two time points (two-wave panel data)

Would the SEM model look something like this? [image: Example SEM model]

Or am I misinterpreting it all?
Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: Looks OK, except you should have a path from X1 to Z2 and Z1 to X2.

Comment: @JeremyMiles

Thanks for your reply! Does it still hold if no relationship is hypothesized between X and Z (implicit constraint to 0), or is it better to first have all the effects included and then respecify the model and remove the insignificant ones?

Because in this example if the two paths you mention are added, the model becomes just-identified, which isn't so interesting empirically. Of course, removing an insignificant path (provided there is one) would solve that issue.

Comment: That's more of a philosophical question. :)  If you remove the two paths, the chi-square test becomes a multivariate test that those two paths are zero. I would probably put them in, you'll get a standard error on them.

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly how I proceeded.